# Enabling Direct3D-specific features (transparency AA)

Tags: c++, transparency, direct3d, antialiasing, ogre3d

I am trying to enable [transparency antialiasing](http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/graphics/2006/04/07/transparency_adaptive_aa_explained/1) in my Ogre-Direct3D application, but it just won't work.

```
HRESULT hres = d3dSystem->getDevice()->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ADAPTIVETESS_Y, (D3DFORMAT)MAKEFOURCC('S', 'S', 'A', 'A'));
/// returned value : hres == S_OK !
```

This method is taken from [NVidia's technical report](http://download.nvidia.com/developer/SDK/Individual_Samples/DEMOS/Direct3D9/src/AntiAliasingWithTransparency/docs/AntiAliasingWithTransparency.pdf).

I **can** enable transparency AA manually through the NVIDIA Control Panel, but surely I can't ask my users to do it like this. Anyone has any idea?

Thank you for your time,

Bill

Comment: Perhaps something in ogre is overriding your render state before it draws your items? You might do better asking on their forums which seem quite active.

Comment: Looks like it is. I had to merge my code into Ogre's code for it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time you have this kind of a problem, be sure to debug what states are currently active et al.

For example you could enable direct3D debug mode and enable state changes logging.
As shown here: http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/10/25/Capture-DirectX-1011-debug-output-to-Visual-Studio.aspx

Hope that helps,
Cheers,
Roel